# Hide price items for specific product categories in Woocommerce email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, email-notifications

I'm using WooCommerce 3.1.1 and I am trying to replace the "price amount" with some text for specific product categories in New order noification for customers and admin.

I have almost tried everything but I am unable to locate the order item detail table for email notifications.

This email looks like this for now:

[image: Email]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you try editing the email template?

Comment: I can't find the code.

Answer (score 2):

You will need **first to read** this official documentation, to learn about  [**Overriding WooCommerce Templates via your active Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

The templates that you need to change and override is [**`emails/email-order-items.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.1.1/templates/emails/email-order-items.php)

At line 58 for your WC version *(Or line 55 in WC version 3.2+)*, you will replace:

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
```

By this *(where you should set your own category and replacement text string)*:

```
<?php
## ---- Variables to define (below)---- ##

$categories = array( 'clothing' ); // The Product categories coma separated (IDs slugs or names)
$replacement_text = __( 'Replacement text (here)' ); // The replacement text

// Getting the email ID global variable (From our function below)
$refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
$email_id = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'];

// When matching product categories, "New Order", "Processing" and "On Hold" email notifications
if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() )
&& ( $email_id == 'new_order' || $email_id == 'customer_processing_order' || $email_id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ) )
    $formated_line_subtotal = $replacement_text;
else
    $formated_line_subtotal = $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item );
?>
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $formated_line_subtotal; ?></td>
```

To Get the email ID you will need to add this in function.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*:

```
// Setting the email_id as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'the_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function the_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}
```

Now you will get this when product category matches and for "New Order" (admin), "Customer On Hold Order" and "Customer Processing Order" email notifications only:

[image]

Comment: This code is working for the email sent to admin but not to the customer.

Comment: @MujtabaK **Updated:** As "New Order" email notification is only sent to Admins, I have added "Customer On-hold Order" and "Customer Processing Order" email notifications in the if statement… This way customer receive it too.

Comment: I updated the code but I am unable to test it. On checkout page it returns it displays an error "Internal Server Error stripe".

Comment: Also, when I tried testing sending an email via backend it redirected me to post.php with the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$formated_line_subtotal' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/clickableco/public_html/demo3/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php on line 72"

Comment: @MujtabaK Sorry there was a missing `)` at the end in `if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && ( $email_id == 'new_order' || $email_id == 'customer_processing_order' || $email_id == 'customer_on_hold_order' ) )` … this time it should work